# Lightstep: Inaccurate UI for child span

Tags: go, opentracing

**Background**

I have a java server that is making an RPC call to a go server. The java rpc client and go rpc server are instrumented with lightstep. Everything about the trace looks normal except for where in the lightstep UI, the go rpc server span is placed.

The java span has ts 1493929521325 which is right before the request is sent to the go server. The go rpc server has 2 timestamps: 1493929521326 is when it received the request and started the span, 1493929521336 is after it responded and finished the span.

**Problem**

I would expect the UI to have the go span horizontally to the immediate right of the java span. Instead, it is far to the right.

The only possible cause I can think of is an incompatibility between v0.10.1 which java code is using and v0.9.1 which go is using. Is this a possibility? Do you have any thoughts on a possible cause?

The go code is essentially:

```
import (
    lightstep "github.com/lightstep/lightstep-tracer-go"
    opentracing "github.com/opentracing/opentracing-go"
)

tracer := lightstep.NewTracer(lightstep.Options{
    AccessToken: ls.AccessToken,
    Collector:   lightstep.Endpoint{ls.Host, ls.Port, true},
    Tags:        map[string]interface{}{lightstep.ComponentNameKey: component},
})

spanContext, err := tracer.Extract(opentracing.TextMap, opentracing.TextMapCarrier(req.GetLightstepData()))
span = tracer.StartSpan(
    endpoint,
    opentracing.ChildOf(spanContext))
}

// handle the request

span.Finish()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Disclaimer: I work at [LightStep]](http://www.lightstep.com)

Sorry you're having trouble getting Java and Go to play well together.  I suspect this is caused by time-correction being enabled in Java but not being used in Go.

You can disable time correction in Java using the `withClockSkewCorrection(boolean clockCorrection)` 
option to turn off clockCorrection when passing in options to the LightStep tracer

Here is the updated [README](https://github.com/lightstep/lightstep-tracer-java#disabling-default-clock-correction) and a link to the [option code](https://github.com/lightstep/lightstep-tracer-java/blob/271ab07d6757c160273d37d3564ea2e8698aa38e/common/src/main/java/com/lightstep/tracer/shared/Options.java#L289)

If you contact us via the [Support] button in LightStep, we should be able to get you sorted out.  Please send us a note so that we can confirm that this is solved for you.

We'll start monitoring SO more carefully so that we catch these things earlier.

Thanks and happy tracing!

Will

Comment: can you please create a lightstep SO tag?